# How to get index based value from Set

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I am looking to store a list of unique string (hence Set) and wanted to retrieve the value based on the index. I used **get(index)** But it turned out it returns **undefined**. So it seems I did not understand Set well.

In case value needed to be retrieved do we have to convert it back to the array and then only read it or with "**get(index)**" it can be achieved?

Also, I have checked [Set tests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to understand **get(index)** but still not clear.

```
const { Set } = require('immutable');

const set = Set(["ab", "cd", "ef"])
console.log(set.get(1)) //logs undefined
console.log(set.toJS()[1]) //logs "cd"
```

Comment: First you need to clarify for yourself if you are using ES6 `Set`, or Immutable.js `Set` - they are different. For one thing, the former doesn't have `get`. And Immutable.js provides `get` for all collections, but with sets it just returns the item itself: `new Immutable.Set().add("foo").get("foo")` returns `"foo"` (and `new Immutable.Set().add("foo").get("bar")` returns `undefined`). Sets are inherently unordered, "set index" makes no sense. If you want indices, you want an array (or at least `Immutable.IndexedSeq`).

Comment: @Amadan thanks for the input, Set's Item is not strict ordered made me use List() and it looks promising. It seems I just scratched surface of Immutable :)

Answer (score 22):

Another way to do that would be to use `Array.from(set)[0]`.

Answer (score 2):

Here I'm trying to using the Set in es2015 directly without `ImmutableJS`:

You could write customized function like this:

```js
Set.prototype.getByIndex = function(index) { return [...this][index]; }

var set = new Set(['a', 'b', 'c'])

console.log(set.getByIndex(0))  // 'a'
```

Note that the spread operator converts a set to an array so that you can use index to get access to the element

Comment: It is bad practice to modify objects that one does not own; this paradigm has already caused problems when [MooTools created their own Array.prototype.flatten](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/03/smooshgate).

Comment: [Here](https://humanwhocodes.com/blog/2010/03/02/maintainable-javascript-dont-modify-objects-you-down-own/) is another good article on the matter. It really makes code less maintainable when you modify objects you don't own.

Answer (score 1):

the way to use Immutable's get is by "key" not by index

```
console.log(set.get("cd")) // logs cd, at index 1
```

if you want to get an element from the Set's iterator, you have to extend Immutable's Set

```
Set.prototype.getByIdx = function(idx){
  if(typeof idx !== 'number') throw new TypeError(`Argument idx must be a Number. Got [${idx}]`);

  let i = 0;
  for( let iter = this.keys(), curs = iter.next(); !curs.done; curs = iter.next(), i++ )
    if(idx === i) return curs.value;

  throw new RangeError(`Index [${idx}] is out of range [0-${i-1}]`);
}

const set = Set(["ab", "cd", "ef"]);

console.log(set.getByIdx(1)) //logs cd
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let data = new Set();
data.add('Value 1');
data.add('Value 2');
data.add('Value 3');

function getSetValueByIndex(setObj, index) {
    return [...setObj][index]
}
console.log(getSetValueByIndex(data, 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Array.from() or spread requires iterating the entire set before returning an example. This is not ideal from a performance perspective.

A better solution would be:

```js
function getSetValueByIndex(target, index) { 
  if (typeof index !== 'number') throw new Error(`Index must be a number!`);

  let i = 0;
  for (const item of target) if (i++ === index) return item;

  throw new Error(`Index ${index} out of bounds!`);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's an improved version of @Ron S. 's answer.
Works with negative indexes, just like Array.at

```
Set.prototype.at = function(index) {
    if (Math.abs(index) > this.size){
        return null;
    }

    let idx = index;
    if (idx < 0){
        idx = this.size + index;
    }
    let counter = 0;
    for (const elem of this){
        if (counter == idx){
            return elem
        }
        counter += 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
this.set = new Set();
set.add(2);
set.add(4);
set.add(8);
console.log(set).  // logs -> Set(3) {2, 4, 8}
console.log([...this.set]);     // logs -> [2, 4, 8]
console.log([...this.set][1]);  // logs -> 4
```

Comment: Yikes. Please don't use `this` to set global variables if you must use them.